# Should I use std::for_each?

Tags: c++, stl, lambda, for-loop, foreach

I'm always trying to learn more about the languages I use (different styles, frameworks, patterns, etc). I've noticed that I never use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) so I thought that perhaps I should start. The goal in such cases is to expand my mind and **not** to improve the code in some measure (readability, expressiveness, compactness, etc).

So with that context in mind, is a good idea to use `std::for_each` for simple tasks like, say, printing out a vector:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n) { cout << n << endl; }
```

(The `[](int n)` being a lambda function). Instead of:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) { cout << v[i] << endl; }
```

I hope this question doesn't seem pointless. I guess it almost asks a larger question... should an intermediate programmer use a language feature even though he doesn't really need to at **this time** but just so that he can understand the feature better for a time that may actually greatly benefit from it. Although this larger question has probably already been asked (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764325/c-standard-library-when-should-i-use-it-and-when-shouldnt-i)).

Comment: If you aren't familiar with a feature, how will you know when it's appropriate to use?

Comment: Define "should".  Performance will almost certainly be identical.  Portability is identical as long as you are talking C++0x.  Readability/maintainability is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: I think a `for_each` + lambda is expressed better as a range-based for: `for (int n : v) { cout << n << endl; }`

Comment: @Greg, just so we are on the same page, familiarity has degrees. For example, I know enough about `for_each` to write the line of code above, but I hardly know much more. Deciding to use it would mean that I google it and learn more as I try to accomplish a specific task.

Comment: To be clear, I'm encouraging you to learn about new features, their advantages and disadvantages, and where they are suitable to use. So yes, learn about it!

Comment: And if we are using C++20, should we use std::ranges::for_each() when we can?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is an advantage to using `std::for_each` instead of an old school `for` loop (or even the newfangled C++0x range-`for` loop):  you can look at the first word of the statement and you know exactly what the statement does.

When you see the `for_each`, you know that the operation in the lambda is performed exactly once for each element in the range (assuming no exceptions are thrown).  It isn't possible to break out of the loop early before every element has been processed and it isn't possible to skip elements or evaluate the body of the loop for one element multiple times.

With the `for` loop, you have to read the entire body of the loop to know what it does.  It may have `continue`, `break`, or `return` statements in it that alter the control flow.  It may have statements that modify the iterator or index variable(s).  There is no way to know without examining the entire loop.

Herb Sutter discussed the advantages of using algorithms and lambda expressions [in a recent presentation to the Northwest C++ Users Group](http://herbsutter.com/2011/05/20/my-lambdas-talk-nwcpp-is-now-online/).

Note that you can actually use the `std::copy` algorithm here if you'd prefer:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: And since the questioner has C++0x, presumably you could do `std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*v.begin())>`. Not sure whether I like it, might just be replacing one annoyance with another.

Comment: The equivalent of `continue` within `for_each` is just `return`.

Answer (score 25):

It depends.

The power of `for_each` is, that you can use it with any container whose iterators satisfy the input iterator concept and as such it's generically useable on any container. That increases maintainability in a way that you can just swap out the container and don't need to change anything. The same doesn't hold true for a loop over the `size` of a vector. The only other containers you could swap it with without having to change the loop would be another random-access one.

Now, if you'd type out the iterator version yourself, the typical version looks like this:

```
// substitute 'container' with a container of your choice
for(std::container<T>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it){
  // ....
}
```

Rather lengthy, eh? C++0x relieves us of that length thing with the `auto` keyword:

```
for(auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it){
  // ....
}
```

Already nicer, but still not perfect. You're calling `end` on every iteration and that can be done better:

```
for(auto it = c.begin(), ite = c.end(); it != ite; ++it){
  // ....
}
```

Looks good now. Still, longer than the equivalent `for_each` version:

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [&](T& item){
  // ...
});
```

With "equivalent" being slightly subjective, as the `T` in the parameter list of the lambda could be some verbose type like `my_type<int>::nested_type`. Though, one can `typedef` his/her way around that. Honestly, I still don't understand why lambdas weren't allowed to be polymorphic with type deduction...

---

Now, another thing to consider is that `for_each`, the name itself, already expresses an intent. It says that no elements in the sequence will be skipped, which might be the case with your normal for-loop.

That brings me to another point: Since `for_each` is intended to run over the whole sequence and apply an operation on *every* item in the container, it is not designed to handle early `return`s or `break`s in general. `continue` can be simulated with a `return` statement from the lambda / functor.

So, use `for_each` where you *really* want to apply an operation on *every* item in the collection.

On a side note, `for_each` might just be "deprecated" with C++0x thanks to the awesome range-based for-loops (also called foreach loops):

```
for(auto& item : container){
  // ...
}
```

Which is way shorter (yay) and allows all three options of:

- returning early (even with a return value!)
- breaking out of the loop and
- skipping over some elements.

Comment: Note that "still, longer than the equivalent `for_each` version" isn't always true:  with the for-loop, you can use `auto` for type deduction, but since lambda expressions are not polymorphic (and don't support type deduction), you must name the actual type in the lambda parameter list, so `T` might be `my_long_class_type` or `my_class_type<unsigned long long>::nested_type` and it might need to be const-qualified, so in fact the code required for the `for_each` is often longer.  That said, when it is appropriate, `for_each` is still superior to a for-loop.

Comment: @James: You're right, I actually wanted to add that too, don't know why I didn't. Editing.

Comment: Though, as Steve Jessop points out in a comment to my answer, you can also use `decltype(*v.begin())`, which while ugly and less readable than a typename, might nonetheless be shorter and in select circumstances might be preferable.

Comment: `for_each` still has an advantage over range-based for in that you can specify start and end points other than `begin()` and `end()`.

Answer (score 9):

I generally would recommend use of `std::for_each`. Your example for loop does not work for non-random-access containers. You can write the same loop using iterators, but it's usually a pain due to writing out `std::SomeContainerName<SomeReallyLongUserType>::const_iterator` as the type of the iteration variable. `std::for_each` insulates you from this, and also amortizes the call to `end` automatically.

Comment: Can't he use `auto` for `std::SomeContainerName<SomeReallyLongUserType>::const_iterator`. (OP is already using C++0x\).

Comment: @iammilind: I suppose that works too... I still like the `for_each` call because 1. the name specifies what it's actually doing, and 2. the iterator syntax is removed from the loop completely. But it's just personal preference -- the constructs are the same, so it's really what one prefers.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, you should try this new features in your **test code**.

In the **production code** you should try the features which you feel comfortable with. (i.e. if you feel comfortable with `for_each`, you can use it.)

Comment: +1 -- Despite my love of Lambdas -- if the OP isn't familiar first he needs to get that way before using them.

Answer (score 3):

`for_each` is the most general of the algorithms that iterate over a sequence, and thus the least expressive. If the goal of the iteration can be expressed in terms of `transform`, `accumulate`, `copy`, I feel that it's better to use the specific algorithm rather than the generic `for_each`.

With the new C++0x range for (supported in gcc 4.6.0, try that out!), `for_each` might even lose its niche of being the most generic way to apply a function to a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop scoping C++11

For example:

```
 T arr[5];
 for (T & x : arr) //use reference if you want write data
 {
 //something stuff...
 }
```

Where T is every type you want.

It works for every containers in STL and classic arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "traditional" example is buggy:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) { cout << v[i] << endl; }
```

This assumes that `int` can always represent the index of every value in the vector.  There are actually two ways this can go wrong.

One is that `int` may be of lower rank than `std::vector<T>::size_type`.  On a 32-bit machine, `int`s are typically 32-bits wide but `v.size()` will almost certainly be 64 bits wide.  If you manage to stuff 2^32 elements into the vector, your index will never reach the end.

The second problem is that you're comparing a signed value (`int`) to an unsigned value (`std::vector<T>::size_type`).  So even if they were of the same rank, when the size exceeds the maximum integer value, then the index will overflow and trigger undefined behavior.

You may have prior knowledge that, *for this vector*, those error conditions will never be true.  But you'd either have to ignore or disable the compiler warnings.  And if you disable them, then you don't get the benefit of those warnings helping you find actual bugs elsewhere in your code.  (I've spent lots of time tracking down bugs that should have been detected by these compiler warnings, if the code had made it feasible to enable them.)

So, yes, `for_each` (or any appropriate `<algorithm>`) is better because it avoids this pernicious abuse of `int`s.  You could also use a range-based for loop or an iterator-based loop with auto.

An additional advantage to using `<algorithm>`s or iterators rather than indexes is that it gives you more flexibility to change container types in the future without refactoring all the code that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Well... that works, but for printing a vector (or the content of other container types) I prefer this :

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, " " ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Range simplifies the use of standard algorithms. For your example you could write:

```
boost::for_each(v, [](int n) { cout << n << endl; });
```

(or `boost::copy` with an ostream iterator as suggested in other answers).