# C++ STL: list with Pointers - Iterator cannot access?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am struggeling with an STL list that holds Pointers of my "Object" object.

I declared:

```
list<Object*> objectlist;
```

and inserted via:

```
this->objectlist.push_back(new Object(address,value,profit));
```

and tried to iterate like in maps and others:

```
list<Object*>::iterator iter;

iter = this->objectlist.begin();

while(iter != this->objectlist.end())
{
    iter->print();
}
```

Where print() is a public Method of class Object;

Whats wrong here?

I cannot access via iterator to the objects in the list ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need  `(*iter)->print();`

Since you have an iterator to a pointer, you have to first de-reference the iterator (which gets you the `Object*`) then the arrow de-references the `Object *` and allows the call to print.

Comment: Yes, your iterator is **not** a pointer to your object type, but an iterator. Also _don't forget your **increment**_ or you will have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 7):

You are not incrementing your iterator! Change your `while` loop to a `for` loop like so:

```
for (list<Object*>::const_iterator iter = this->objectlist.begin(),
     end = this->objectlist.end();
     iter != end;
     ++iter)
{
    (*iter)->print();
}
```

(Also `iter` *dereferences* to a pointer, like the other answers have pointed out.)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the value pointed by iterator with *iter

Also, remember to increment the iterator in each iteration. Otherwise you get stuck in an endless loop.

Like this:

```
iter = this->objectlist.begin();

while(iter != this->objectlist.end())
{
    (*iter)->print();
    iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the C++11 way (if possible). The dereference of the iterator comes free :)

```
for (auto& iter: this->objectlist)
{
     iter->print();
}
```

Also if print() is a const function you should use

```
for (const auto& iter: this->objectlist)
```

Comment: 2 questions:
  - "i" should be "iter", right?
  - is the "&" needed?  Seems to work fine without it too

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `for`-loop you should use STL's `for_each()` - see the [advantages of for_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047414/advantages-of-stdfor-each-over-for-loop) over a simple `for`-loop.

### Syntax

```
#include <algorithm> // 'for_each()' is in there

std::for_each(InputIterator first, // Iterator start position
              InputIterator last,  // Iterator end position
              Function fn);        // Unary function - executed on all elements in range
```

### `for_each` example

Here's how your example looks `std::for_each()` instead of `for( ... )`:

```
list<Object*> objectlist;

// insert some elements …

// Deletes all elements of 'objectlist'
std::for_each(objectlist.begin(), objectlist.end(), DeleteObj<Object*>());
```

#### Unary function

The unary function is implemented using a template, so you can use it with *any* type. Just make sure ***`T` is a pointer type***!

```
template<class T> class DeleteObj
{
public:
    bool operator()(T obj) const
    {
        delete obj;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Btw. you *don't have* to implement this as template. And: you can *bind* a member function instead of such a implementation too!

#### Documentation

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/
- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each
- [Should I use std::for_each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260600/should-i-use-stdfor-each)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following way:

```
(*iter)->print()
```

Comment: Something more to say:  *iter means the element, so you should first get the element, and then to use it.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator references an element in the list, so for a list of type `T`, dereferencing an iterator yields a value of type `T`.

In your case, `T` is actually a pointer - `Object*`. Hence, the `iter->` call (which dereferences the iterator) yields a pointer. You have to dereference that pointer to get to the actuala object.

Try using

```
(*iter)->print()
```

instead.