# selecting a single member from each structure in a std::vector into another vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project where I would like to copy one struct element of a vector of that struct type to a new vector. For example:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    long b;
};

std::vector< Foo > v1;
std::vector< long > v2;

for( std::vector< Foo >::const_iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it )
{
    v2.push_back( it->b );
}
```

Is there a better/more elegant way than this?

Thanks,
 PaulH

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Visual C++ 2008, no, this is about as "elegant" as it gets.  The Standard Library provides algorithms that can be used to manipulate containers, but in most scenarios--especially in simple use cases like this one--they are far too cumbersome to use.

C++11 adds lambda expressions to C++.  Visual C++ 2010 and recent versions of other C++ compilers support this C++11 feature.  With lambda expressions, you can easily use the `transform` algorithm for your task:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2),
               [](Foo const& x) { return x.b; });
```

Without lambda expressions, you'd have to define a function to extract the `b` element from the struct:

```
long get_b(Foo const& x) { return x.b; }
```

You could then use this function with the `transform` algorithm:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), get_b);
```

However, for simple use cases like this, this can quickly lead to unwieldy code as it is difficult to neatly keep all of the related functions together.

Comment: And, of course, there are other techniques, like Boost.Lambda, or writing general-purpose transformers and using them with the Standard Library binders, but none of these techniques could be considered _more elegant_ than what is in the original code.

Comment: You can also use `std::bind(&Foo::b)` to get a function of signature `long&(Foo&)`, I think.

Comment: I've tried to completely block `bind` out of my memory, though I fear some scars will remain forever. :-O

Comment: @Kerrek : Including the missing placeholder, naturally.

Comment: And for what reason the `std::transform` loop using a lambda would be "better" for this task? Excluding the "Hey guys! look... I used lambdas!" effect of course...

Comment: @6502:  The only reason to use a lambda with `transform` is that it makes the code simpler and easier to understand than using something like your `MemberGetter`, `std::bind`, or related techniques.  Algorithms are preferable over loops in most cases for the same reason:  they make code clearer, simpler, and easier to understand.  Cf. my answer to ["Should I use std::for_each?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260709/151292) for why I argue for usage of algorithms over loops.

Comment: I used `MemberGetter` because it allows the selection of member to be copied to be a runtime parameter. If that is not needed and the member is fixed I said that the best option is simply the loop. I'm not sure if I agree that for a fixed member (like in your example) even in C++11 (unrelated to the question, btw) this code is better for any reasonable definition of better.

Comment: @6502 : The question is tagged `c++` and the current C++ standard is C++11, so C++11 is entirely relevant.

Comment: @ildjarn: The very first phrase is saying that the OP is using a compiler NOT supporting C++11: I said it's not related to the question, not that it's not relevant to the tags.

Comment: @6502 : Ah, fair enough, I was paying more attention to the answers than the question. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean with "better".

If you mean if the same can be written by using template trickery then the answer is yes:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
struct MemberGetter
{
    T C::*mp;
    MemberGetter(T C::*mp) : mp(mp) { }
    T operator()(const C& c) { return c.*mp; }
};

struct Foo
{
    double dm;
};

...
std::vector<double> x;
std::vector<Foo> y;

std::transform(y.begin(), y.end(),
               std::back_inserter(x),
               MemberGetter<Foo, double>(&Foo::dm));
```

This is in my opinion worse than an explicit loop, but has the advantage that the member pointer (i.e. which part of the structure you are copying) can be a runtime parameter.

If the member you need to copy is instead known and fixed then I'd say that the explicit loop is the best way (I can barely imagine corner cases in which using a similar template where the member pointer is a template parameter makes any sense).