# Preferred standard use: range based for or std::for_each

Tags: c++, coding-style, c++11

In [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), there are two loops over all elements (range based for and for_each). Is there any reason to prefer one over the other or are there situations where one is a better fit?

```
for (auto& elem: container) {
  // do something with elem
}

std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(),
              [](Elem& elem) {
                // do something with elem
              });
```

My idea would be that the first is simpler and is similar to range based loops in other languages while the second also works for sequences that are not complete containers and the second is more similar to other `std`-algorithms.

Comment: I'm curious about the way to actually properly *use* range-based for, so please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994789/proper-style-for-declaration-in-range-based-for

Comment: I added a simple `for_each` example. I thought I'd seen a message asking for one but I'm not so sure any more...

Comment: @juanchopanza: I asked for one based on the lambda's, but I removed it because at the time I posted the comment, I read Potatoswatter's comment that querying a lambda was not possible.  Still, it is a nice example of where for_each might be a better fit.

Comment: Just remember that `for_each` (and range-based for, like it) should generally be your *last* choice of algorithms. Usually, something more specialized to the task at hand will be a better choice.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: actually last but one, there is still the classic for(;;) if all else fails...

Comment: @stefaanv: well, yes, there is that.

Comment: Largely a duplicate of [Should I use std::for_each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260600/should-i-use-stdfor-each)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: even though the question isn't that similar, your answer also answers my question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Range-based `for` is obviously simpler to read and write. It is specialized for this task.

   **EDIT:** You can break form a range-for without abusing an exception. (Although `std::find_if` substituted for `std::for_each` allows this as well.)
2. `std::for_each`, ironically, is the alternative which is actually range based and allows you to select particular `begin` and `end` values instead of the whole container. (**EDIT:** This can be hacked around using a simple `range` class providing `begin` and `end` members, such as provided by Boost.)

   Also `for_each` may be more elegant when otherwise using higher-order functions: it can be used as an argument to `bind`, and the third argument is already a functor.

Mainly it's a matter of style. Most readers probably prefer to see `for ( auto &a : b )` though, and most implementations now support it.

Comment: +1 indeed, the fact that you can chose the range in the `for_each` is very powerful.

Comment: @juanchopanza: of course, if you use a `Range` container (such as `Boost.Range`), then this advantage is moot.

Comment: You might want to add that only range-for allow for break and continue.

Comment: @Klaim: `for_each` supports `continue` via `return` from the lambda (or function, or functor). For `break`-like behavior, one might use `find_if` or another more appropriate algorithm.

Comment: One reason I'd prefer a ranged `for` over a `std::for_each` is that (at least in VS2013 which I use at work), the `for_each` method cannot be easily debugged.  You can set a breakpoint in the middle of the loop body but it will never trip.  With a ranged `for`, breakpoints will work as expected when debugging.

Comment: Ironically, what you mention about `for_each` is precisely a valid reason one could use it: it is immediately obvious this runs for all elements of the collection. No need read the loop body to check for a `break`.

Answer (score 19):

`std::for_each` returns the functor that has been used internally in the loop, so it provides a clean mechanism to gather some information concerning the elements in the sequence. The range based for loop is just a loop, so any state that is to be used outside of the loop has to be declared outside of that scope. In your example, if the purpose of the of the loops is to mutate each element of the sequence, then there isn't much difference at all. But if you are not using the return value of the `for_each` then you're probably better off with the simple loop. By the way, the range based loop works on C-style arrays and std::strings too.

This is an example of using the return value of `for_each`, although it is not a very imaginative or useful one. It is just to illustrate the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo {
  void operator()(int i) { if (i > 4) sum += i;}
  int sum{0};
};

int main() {

  std::array<int, 10> a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  Foo foo = std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), Foo());
  std::cout << "Sum " << foo.sum << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1, but note that there's no way to query a lambda functor anyway; obtaining auxiliary state would be done through a capture variable, which would work just the same in either construct.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Good point. Or by creating a function object from the lambda.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Indeed, the situation fortunately improved from C++03 here too. In C++03 it was unspecified if you would get a full result (because of copies), while in C++11 only move operations are used.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++17, `std::for_each` also supports [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).

For example, by writing the code below, you are telling the compiler that the loop can be parallelized:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [](int &n){ ++n; });
```

You cannot do the same with a range-based `for` loop.