# Proper style for declaration in range-based for

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, perfect-forwarding

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994421/153285) mentioned the obvious, idiomatic usage of C++11 range-based for.

```
for (auto& elem: container) {
  // do something with elem
}
```

I've been having doubts about the kind of reference you're supposed to use, though. Input iterators may return rvalues. Although the implicit type introduced by `auto` could be deduced to `const` which would bind to an rvalue, that doesn't seem to occur.

Is the best general practice to use perfect forwarding?

```
for (auto && elem: container) {
  // do something with elem
}
```

I see no downside here, but it looks a little too cute. Maybe I still just haven't written enough C++11.

Comment: For the poor MSVC10 users who can't enjoy range based for, the same question applies to `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: `auto` is never `const`. You need to say `auto const &`. Also, `auto &&` isn't an rvalue reference, but more of a "universal reference".

Comment: @KerrekSB Good info that `const` isn't deduced there. I never said anything about rvalue references ;v)

Comment: I should add that I don't really mean "never": of course `const int a = 1; auto & ra = a;` works as expected. But `auto` never becomes more const than it needs to.

Comment: @KerrekSB can you clarify? `const` is deduced in a function argument context, and `auto` is defined in terms of that, with no exceptions. This seems to work fine: `int const i = 5;
auto &x = i;` **EDIT** haha, alright :v) . Well, in any case it doesn't guess that an lvalue reference should be made const to bind to an rvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, some general advice on how to use `auto` that is not specific to range-for. `auto&&` can be problematic if the initializer is an xvalue referring to a temporary, since lifetime extension may not be applied in this case. To put it more simply, and with code:

```
// Pass-through identity function that doesn't construct objects
template<typename T>
T&&
id(T&& t)
{ return std::forward<T>(t); }

// Ok, lifetime extended
// T {} is a prvalue
auto&& i = T {};

T* address = &i;

// Still ok: lifetime of the object referred to by i exceed that of j
// id(whatever) is an xvalue
auto&& j = id(std::move(i));

// No other object is involved or were constructed,
// all those references are bound to the same object
assert( &j == address );

// Oops, temporary expires at semi-colon
// id(whatever) is an xvalue, again
auto&& k = id(T {});
```

The big clue that there's something shady going on here is that `id` has return type `T&&`. If it returned `T` then `id(whatever)` would be a prvalue, and the returned temporary would have had its lifetime extended (however that would involve a construction).

---

With that out of the way, when it comes to range-for though you have to remember that `for(auto&& ref: init) { /* body */ }` is specified to be roughly equivalent to the following (ignoring some details that don't matter here):

```
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto&& range = init;
    for(auto b = begin(range), e = end(range); b != e; ++b) {
        auto&& ref = *b;
        /* body */
    }
}
```

We need to ask ourselves now, what if `*b` is an xvalue (i.e. the iterator type has an `operator*` returning `value_type&&`, as is the case e.g. with `std::move_iterator<Iterator>`)? It must then refer to an object that *will* outlive `ref`, since the line `auto&& ref = *b;` involves no temporary. Hence it's safe. Otherwise, if `*b` is a prvalue (i.e. the iterator type has an `operator*` returning `T` for some object type `T`), then the lifetime of the temporary gets extended for the rest of the loop body. In all cases you're safe (the case where `*b` is an lvalue being left as an exercise to the reader).

I personally make heavy use of `auto&&`, with or without range-for. But I do ask myself every time whether the initializer is an xvalue or not, and if it is, what is the lifetime of what is being referred to.

Comment: Good info. Another perspective… the only temporary that a function could return an xvalue to is an rvalue argument. `begin` and `end` take no arguments, therefore forwarding their results is safe.

Comment: @Potatoswatter In this instance it is `*b` that is of interest (and that doesn't indeed take arguments, much less temporary argument as you rightfully analysed). `begin` and `end` do take arguments, but they only work with lvalues.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the `begin` and `end` *members*, and excluding `this` because it's an lvalue. `operator*` takes an argument in essentially the same sense as `begin` and `end`. But yeah, that's the one that really counts.