# Is auto& or auto&& prefered for modifying a range with range based foor loop?

Tags: c++, foreach

STL's(person) recent proposal for implicit auto&& in range based for loop made me wonder what it the proper way to iterate and modify elements of a sequence

```
for(auto&& elem: cont)
{
}
```

or

```
for(auto& elem: cont)
{
}
```

Comment: or of [Proper style for declaration in range-based for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994789/proper-style-for-declaration-in-range-based-for)

Comment: A rvalue reference is a normal reference _which can also bind to a temporary_. Do you see a temporary?

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent; in the first case, "reference collapsing" means that the type of `elem` becomes an *lvalue* reference since its initialiser is an *lvalue*. I'd say the second is more "proper" since it expresses what's actually happening.

(Unless, as pointed out in the duplicate's answer, the container breaks the container requirements as `std::vector<bool>` does, with a `reference` type that isn't actually a reference type. In that case, the first will bind `elem` to a temporary of that type, while the second won't compile.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/700825

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Fair enough, I didn't consider non-conformant containers like `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: regarding vector<bool> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx and technically vector<bool> is not a container, though im sure you know that...    http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "proper"; it depends on what you're iterating over and what you want to do with each iteree.