# How is the range-based loop different to a for-each loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

The latest C++ 11 specification defines a new type of for loop called "range-based for loop".
Its looks and mechanics appear to be pretty much identical to the for-each loops available in other languages.

What are the differences between the two of them, if any? If there are no differences why the new name?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm not looking for implementation differences between the "range based for" of c++ and other languages' for each or std::for_each. Instead I was wondering if there was some hidden value behind the fact that they decided to call this new c++ "feature" (or syntax, or idiom or whatever you want to call it) "range-based for loop" instead of "for each loop" as pretty much anyone else seems to be calling these things.

Comment: No diff. Just native C++ foreach

Comment: by for each, do you mean std::for_each?

Comment: the differences depend on the language you compare to, so I think you need to be more specific about that.

Comment: I mean the generalized for-each idiom available natively in lots of languages. I'm not trying to discuss the differences between two different implementations (I'm sure there are subtle differences there) but I'm wondering whether there is some big conceptual differentiating quality in range-based loop which I missing.

Comment: It's not a new name, since `for` was always a reserved keyword; it just adds a new unambiguous syntax variation. `foreach` as a keyword would have broken existing code, it would have taken away some some the brevity the range-based for offers and would not have had any benefit.

Comment: @leftaroundabout To be fair, the benefit would have been a slightly improved readability … there’s a reason most other languages chose `foreach` or `for … in …`. Of course that doesn’t outweigh the disadvantage you mentioned.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree `for … in …` is more readable, but `foreach` on its own doesn't really add anything.

Comment: c.f. [Preferred standard use: range based for or std::for_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994421/preferred-standard-use-range-based-for-or-stdfor-each)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Syntax:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement
```

produces code equivalent to:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr(__range); 
    auto __end = end_expr(__range); 
    for (;__begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

While the `std::for_each` applies unary function to the specified range. So, there are two basic differences:

- The range-based for-loop syntax is cleaner and more universal, but you can't execute the code in loop for a specified range different than from `begin()` to `end()`.
- Range-based for-loop can be applied to containers which don't have iterators defined, by defining `begin()` and `end()` functions.

You cannot compare it to the "generalized for-each idiom", because **there is no standard idiom**. To compare, you have to point out the concrete implementation and the **difference is usually hidden in the details**.

Comment: He doesn't talk about `std::for_each`. He is talking about having a keyword `foreach` like other languages have.

Comment: @Naveen: If you removed `auto`, it wouldn't even be correct any more. `auto` does magic reference type deduction which you cannot express without it.

Comment: hm i would say that the thing the range based for loop uses comes to being an iterator.

Comment: +1 for "_you can't execute the code in loop for a specified range different than from `begin()` to `end()`_". That's why `std:for_each()` will continue to exist. Not everyone works with the whole of every container every time. This is true for as long as functions taking pairs of iterators exist; I guess, ideally, eventually the Ranges TS will supplant it (since I presume one can form a range object expressing a sub-range of a container and range-`for` over that).

Answer (score 6):

> What are the differences between the two of them, if any? **If there are no differences why the new name?**

In fact, it is the old name : `for`.

If you meant why C++ doesn't add a new name, such as `foreach`, to the language like other  languages have done, then you tell us why add a *new* name when old name works fine?

---

From your comment:

> But to my knowledge all others call this type of syntax a "for-each loop". The new name for the concept had me asking if there is indeed more differences than I can see.

Alright. It is about the terminologies : *for-each-loop* vs. *range-based-for-loop*.

I think it is because C++ range-based-for-loop basically iterates *all elements in the range* defined by *std::begin(c)* and *std::end(c)*. In other words, the name *range-based-for-loop* emphasizes the philosophy of `begin` and `end` iterators which define the *range*.

To explain that further, range-based-for-loop would work only for those collection for which `begin()` and `end()` are defined:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int a[100];
int *p = new int[100];

for(int i : v) {} // works :  begin(v) and end(v) are defined
for(int i : a) {} // works :  begin(a) and end(a) are defined
for(int i : p) {} // does not work :  begin(p) and end(p) are not defined
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not actually calling for introducing a new keyword `foreach` or such. `for (something : somethings)` works fine. Not all other languages use a `foreach` keyword. But to my knowledge all others call this type of syntax a "for-each loop". The new name for the concept had me asking if there is indeed more differences than I can see.

Comment: @Nawaz: liked your explanation & example for calling it a range-based-for-loop

Comment: @sri: Wow... you're here, enjoying?

Answer (score -3):

It's a standard foreach implementation - only syntactic sugar - added for convenience.