# What are the benefits of using for_each vs. range-for?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I know historically it was better to use standard algorithms such as `for_each` instead of a `for` loop because they were just more readable. But I just feel like with c++11 the regular for loop is far more terse than the numerous standard algorithms with their corresponding callback functors.

Am I wrong to think this? Are many of the standard algorithms obsolete? What are the different benefits offered by those approaches?

Comment: for_each will be parallelizable when the parallel stl comes into the standard. Library constructs allow more abstraction than language features alone sometimes. So I think that for that reason for_each could be better when migrating code.

Comment: @GermánDiago is there anything in the standard preventing parallelization of range-for-loops? I'd expect the standard to require "as-if regular for loop" but leave the implementation details (including parallelization) open.

Comment: As far as I know loops will be implementation-defined? I never wondered this actually. What I know is that you can have guaranteed parallelization with the parallel stl, so why should you depend on implementation when you can have something safer?

Comment: @GermánDiago I see your point now, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You can `break` a for-loop, while you can not `break` a `for_each`, so they are not 100% equivalent. I'd use `for_each` whenever it is possible.

Comment: Why does your title specify `for_each`, but the body talks about some mysterious "_the numerous standard algorithms with their corresponding callback functors_" and "_many of the standard algorithms_"? What specific `<algorithm>`s other than `for_each()` are relevant here? How can those be replaced by range-`for` loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred standard use: range based for or std::for\_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994421/preferred-standard-use-range-based-for-or-stdfor-each)

Answer (score 4):

Use your judgement.

Many algorithms have become much easier to use in C++11 thanks to lambdas and better bind expressions, which allow you to specify the functor in a relatively concise fashion. However, the range-based `for` loop is a perfectly legitimate option, too.

If all you need is one or two statements in the loop body, then by all means use a range-based loop. If you need to call a member function on a collection of objects, maybe use `for_each` and `mem_fn`. If a bind expression looks clear enough, use it. But whatever you do, if you find yourself cramming too much logic into one place, consider refactoring and giving readable names to smaller components of work.

C++ offers you many tools, and the existence of one tool doesn't mean that another is useless. Large toolbelts, just like C++, target experienced users, and experience will let you choose the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of readability, using a range-based for is now probably slightly better than using `std::for_each`. This doesn't necessarily means that `for_each` is obsolete, though.

Consider this code:

```
auto myVals = getManyValsInAContainer();

for (auto& val : myVals)
{
    doStuff(val);
}
```

It does the same thing that this less readable code:

```
auto myVals = getManyValsInAContainer();

for (auto it = myVals.begin(), end = myVals.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    doStuff(*it);
}
```

Now, let's say your container is an `std::deque`, which means that your values are in big blocks of contiguous memory, with a few pointers to keep track of where those blocks are. For someone who knows the implementation, iterating over all elements of that container is easy: it simply requires a double loop to go through *each* element of *each* block.

But what about range-based for? It relies on `operator++()` to move from one element to the next. Each time it does, `operator++()` has to check whether the next element is in the same block or if it needs to proceed to the next block. Those calls are totally independent from each other, so there's no way to make things more efficient.

(Note: don't try to do things manually instead: you would need access to private parts of the container for that, and even if you had it, whatever you come up with would only work for some implementations of the STL but not others)

Is anything different when it comes to `std::for_each` then? Well, for one thing it's a function template, so it can be specialized. It's also part of the STL, which means that the people who implemented it know exactly how `std::deque` (or whatever other STL container you're using) is implemented, and that they can make `std::for_each` a friend of the container classes (or do whatever else they need to do) to do things efficiently instead of relying on multiple calls to `operator++()`.

So, there's your answer: `std::for_each` is not obsolete. Readability was only one of the things it had going for it, but it's still more efficient than any for loop when iterating over an STL container.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a rather subjective topic, but for what it's worth I agree with you. I think it's much better to use language constructs over library constructs, particularly when the language construct is concise and readable. (There was certainly an argument for readability of `for_each` over prior to c++11 though)

Comment: I tend to agree. OTOH, with C++11 lambdas, one at least does not have to write a lot of functor classes nowadays.

Comment: @ErikAlapää I loath C++ lambdas. The Boost.Phoenix ones always looked better and resulted in far less syntax noise for small functions. Compare `[](int a, int b){return a+b;}` to `_1+_2`.

Comment: Some lambda is better than no lambda, but I have to agree with @KitsuneYMG.