# Why would I want to implement my own doubly linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, list

Apart from the academic aspect of learning something from implementing my own doubly linked list in C++, is there any actual real-world advantage of implementing my own doubly linked list when there is already std::list? Can I make things more efficient on my own for a certain task, or has std::list been refined so much over the years that it is the optimal implementation of a doubly linked list in most cases?

Comment: Somehow I feel this question is like going into a mechanics workshop and yell "Why would I invent my own engine"?. Usually, because you don't _know_ that there's already a good engine, or because you doubt that the standard engine is really that good for your work. But first, you should test the engine, it's usually good for you. In doubt, have a look at the actual `std::list` implementation and then forget about implementing it yourself.

Comment: A number of use cases here: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Applications_of_doubly_linked_list

Comment: You should look into writing your own allocator before writing your own `std::list` replacement.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764325/c-standard-library-when-should-i-use-it-and-when-shouldnt-i/4764375#4764375

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any actual real-world advantage of implementing my own doubly linked list when there is already std::list?

Probably not.

> Can I make things more efficient on my own for a certain task,

Maybe - depends on the task.  You might only need a singly linked list, which might end up being faster, for example.

> or has std::list been refined so much over the years that it is the optimal implementation of a doubly linked list in most cases?

Probably.

The best answer to all of this stuff is probably "use the standard implementation until it doesn't work, and then figure out what you're going to do about it."

Comment: These days, there's `std::forward_list` if you only need a singly linked list.

Answer (score 2):

*"Why would I want to **implement** a doubly linked list in C++?"*

You would not. Even if you *needed* a doubly linked list, you would avoid reinventing the wheel and *use an existing implementation*.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask that question, the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

You would almost never want or need to implement your own `list`.  For that matter, you would almost never want or need to reimplement your own *anything* if it is covered by the Standard Library.

There are exceptions.  Those exceptions are, well... exceptional.  Exceptions are made for performance reasons, typically when the performance requirements are extreme.  But these exceptions can only be responsibly made when you have already proved that the Standard Library-provided functionality is a measurable problem for your specific use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for a doubly-linked list to be more efficient than `std::list` for a certain task. There's an algorithmic complexity trade-off in `std::list`, and your task might benefit from the opposite decision.

Specifically, `std::list` is required in C++11, and recommended in C++03, to have constant-time `size()`. That is, the number of elements must be stored in the object.

This means that the 4-argument version of `splice()` necessarily has *linear* complexity, because it needs to count the number of elements moved from one list to another in order to update both sizes (except in some special cases, like the source list being empty after the splice, or the two lists being the same object).

However, if you're doing a lot of splicing then you might prefer to have these the other way around -- constant-time `splice()` and a `size()` function that is linear-time in the worst case (when a splice has been done on the list more recently than the last time the size was updated).

As it happens, GNU's implementation of `std::list` made this choice, and had to change for C++11 conformance. So even if this is what you want, you don't necessarily have to completely implement it yourself. Just dust off the old GNU code and change the names so that it's valid user code.